# Filtering Indri Search Results by Tweet Creation Date

Tags: python, indri

In my project, I'm using Indri for information retrieval on the TREC 2011 corpus dataset. After successfully indexing my data, I'm now running queries with `IndriRunQuery`.

My problem lies in incorporating a specific condition in my search. I want to retrieve only the tweets that were published before the creation date of my query. That is, any tweet that was published after my query was created should not be considered in the search results.

To execute my search, I'm currently using the following parameters:

```
IndriRunQuery.exe E:\projet\requete\requete.xml -index=E:\projet\indexfinal -count=1500 -trecFormat=true -queryOffset=0 -printDocuments=true > "E:\projet\resultatt recherhe 2\resultarequet1.txt"
```

I execute this with `IndriRunQuery` `query.txt`. But so far, I have not been able to find a way to add the tweet creation date as a condition in my search.

Can anyone guide me on how to include the tweet creation date as a condition in my Indri search?